# When WSO2 esb gives base64 code response in wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 4.7.01 version. I am receiving xml response from esb whenever there is a success response. But sometimes I will receive a base64 encoded format response from esb whenever there is a soap:server or soap:client or customized error response is returned from application server. Even though I am isung Accept property to while sending the request I am getting the above said kind of response. How to handle or avoid this kind of response from esb.

for exampleL

```
<axis2ns65:binary xmlns:axis2ns65="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0nMS4wJyBlbmNvZGluZz0nVVRGLTgnPz48c29hcDpFbnZlbG9wZSB4bW
xuczpzb2FwPSJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy9zb2FwL2VudmVsb3BlLyI+PHNvYXA6Qm9k
eT48cmVzcG9uc2U+PHN0YXR1c0NvZGU+R0xYMDAxNTI5PC9zdGF0dXNDb2RlPjxzdGF0dXNNZXNzYWdlPkludm
FsaWQgVmVoaWNsZSBJZHMgYXJlOjg1MDA4PC9zdGF0dXNNZXNzYWdlPjxzdGF0dXM+ZmFpbHVyZTwvc3RhdHVz
PjwvcmVzcG9uc2U+PC9zb2FwOkJvZHk+PC9zb2FwOkVudmVsb3BlPg==
</axis2ns65:binary>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body><axis2ns182:binary xmlns:axis2ns182="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">
</axis2ns182:binary>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following steps

1. Open {ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
2. un-comment the following

   <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>

   <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will follow this steps.

Comment: Hi Nadeesha, After following your suggestions also I am still facing the same issue. Any thing else I need to do.